# How to get scanf to continue with empty scanset

Tags: c, unicode, scanf

I am currently trying to parse [UnicodeData.txt](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/UnicodeData.txt) with this format: ftp://ftp.unicode.org/Public/3.0-Update/UnicodeData-3.0.0.html However, I am hitting a problem in that when I try to read, say a line like the following.

```
something;123D;;LINE TABULATION;
```

I try to get the data from the fields by code such as the following. The problem is that fields[3] is not getting filled in, and scanf is returning 2. `in` is the current line.

```
char fields[4][256];
sscanf(in, "%[^;];%[^;];%[^;];%[^;];%[^;];",
    fields[0], fields[1], fields[2], fields[3]);
```

I know this is the correct implementation of `scanf()`, but is there a way to get this to work, short of making my own `scanf()`?

Comment: why are you reading 5 times using 5 % ?

Comment: Why do you think this is correct behavior for `scanf()`? I would expect `fields[2]` to be filled in with a blank string and `fields[3]` to be filled in with `LINE TABULATION`. And that is exactly what `scanf()` does in my C++ compiler (C++Builder XE2), which makes me think this is a bug in your compiler's `scanf()` implementation.

Comment: it's actually the correct behaviour for `scanf`, see my answer below...

Comment: I hate `scanf` family

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`scanf` does not handle "empty" fields. So you will have to parse it on your own.

The following solution is:

- fast, as it uses `strchr` rather than the quite slow `sscanf`
- flexible, as it will detect an arbitrary number of fields, up to a given maximum.

The function `parse` extracts fields from the input `str`, separated by semi-colons. Four semi-colons give five fields, some or all of which can be blank. No provision is made for escaping the semi-colons.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static int parse(char *str, char *out[], int max_num) {
    int num = 0;
    out[num++] = str;
    while (num < max_num && str && (str = strchr(str, ';'))) {
        *str = 0;           // nul-terminate previous field
        out[num++] = ++str; // save start of next field
    }
    return num;
}

int main(void) {
    char test[] = "something;123D;;LINE TABULATION;";
    char *field[99];
    int num = parse(test, field, 99);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
        printf("[%s]", field[i]);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The output of this test program is:

```
[something][123D][][LINE TABULATION][]
```

**Update**: A slightly shorter version, which doesn't require an extra array to store the start of each substring, is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static int replaceSemicolonsWithNuls(char *p) {
    int num = 0;
    while ((p = strchr(p, ';'))) {
        *p++ = 0;
        num++; 
    }
    return num;
}

int main(void) {
    char test[] = "something;123D;;LINE TABULATION;";
    int num = replaceSemicolonsWithNuls(test);
    int i;
    char *p = test;
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++, p += strlen(p) + 1)
        printf("[%s]", p);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Even when this is not strictly a `scanf` method, it is still a good alternate solution if you want to send the data to array, like in my case. Thanks you, Joseph.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you would like to consider this following alternative, using `scanf`s and `"%n"` format-specifier, used for reading in how many characters have been read by far, into an integer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 4

int main( ){

    char * str = "something;123D;;LINE TABULATION;";
    char * wanderer = str;
    char fields[N][256] = { 0 };
    int n;

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) {
        n = 0;
        printf( "%d ", sscanf( wanderer, "%255[^;]%n", fields[i], &n ) );
        wanderer += n + 1;
    }

    putchar( 10 );

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
        printf( "%d: %s\n", i, fields[i] );

    getchar( );
    return 0;
}
```

On every cycle, it reads maximum of 255 characters into the corresponding `fields[i]`, until it encounters a delimiter semicolon `;`. After reading them, it reads in how many characters it had read, into the `n`, which had been *zeroed* (oh my...) beforehand.

It increases the pointer that points to the string by the amount of characters read, plus one for the delimiter semicolon.

`printf` for the return value of `sscanf`, and the printing of the result is just for demonstration purposes. You can see the code working on http://codepad.org/kae8smPF without the `getchar();` and with `for` declaration moved outside for C90 compliance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `sscanf` will do what you need: `sscanf` format `%[^;]` will match a **non-empty** sequence of *not-semicolon* characters. The alternative would be using `readline` with the separator being `';'`, like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main() {
  using namespace std;
  istringstream i { "something;123D;;LINE TABULATION;\nsomething;123D;;LINE TABULATION;\nsomething;123D;;LINE TABULATION;\n" };
  string a, b, c, d, newline;
  while( getline(i, a, ';') && getline(i, b, ';') && getline(i, c, ';') && getline (i, d, ';') && getline(i, newline) )
    cout << d << ',' << c << '-' << b << ':' << a << endl; 
}
```

(I have only seen you took the `c++` tag off this question now, if your problem is c-only, I have another solution, below:)

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  typedef char buffer[2048];
  buffer line;
  while( fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) > 0 ) {
    printf("(%s)\n", line);
    char *end = line;
    char *s1 = *end == ';' ? (*end = '\0'), end++ : strtok_r(end, ";", &end);
    char *s2 = *end == ';' ? (*end = '\0'), end++ : strtok_r(end, ";", &end);
    char *s3 = *end == ';' ? (*end = '\0'), end++ : strtok_r(end, ";", &end);
    char *s4 = *end == ';' ? (*end = '\0'), end++ : strtok_r(end, ";", &end);
    printf("[%s][%s][%s][%s]\n", s4, s3, s2, s1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Argh. Sometimes I just think the STL is a little ugly, but I guess this is the only way. Thanks very much!

Comment: @trolleyman: I guess _I_ am one of the people that think it's just beautiful, so we'll have to agree on disagreeing (on the beauty of the STL) **but** anyway, I put a C-only solution above! (and yes, `strtok`/`strtok_r` **skips** empty fields, so we have to take care of them separately...) :D