# Sscanf with regex to match even an empty string

Tags: php, regex, scanf

I am using this regex in sscanf

```
sscanf($seat, "%d-%[^(](%[^@]@%[^)])");
```

And it works well when i'm getting this kind of strings:
`173-9B(AA@3.45 EUR@32H)`
but when i'm getting this kind of string:
`173-9B(@3.14 EUR@32H)`

it's all messed up, how can I also accept empty strings between the first `(` and the first `@` ?

Comment: Any reason of using sscanf instead of `preg_match`?

Comment: @anubhava not in particular, just that it was more convenient for me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22974628/how-to-get-scanf-to-continue-with-empty-scanset#:~:text=scanf%20does%20not%20handle%20%22empty%22%20fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be better off using a regex in `preg_match` to handle optional data presence in input:

```
$re = '/(\d*)-([^(]*)\(([^@]*)@([^)]*)\)/';

preg_match($re, '173-9B(@3.45 EUR@32H)', $m);
unset($m[0]);
print_r($m);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [1] => 173
    [2] => 9B
    [3] =>
    [4] => 3.45 EUR@32H
)
```

**And 2nd example:**

```
preg_match($re, '173-9B(AA@3.45 EUR@32H)', $m);
unset($m[0]);
print_r($m);

Array
(
    [1] => 173
    [2] => 9B
    [3] => AA
    [4] => 3.45 EUR@32H
)
```

Use of `([^@]*)` will make it match 0 more characters that are not `@`.